# Name resolution failure attempting to reach service in region eu-west-1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-powershell

I installed AWS for Powershell Tools on 3 machines - two Windows servers and one desktop Windows PC. Using the same configuration, one server fails with the error

> GET-S3Bucket Name resolution failure attempting to reach service in region eu-west-1 (as supplied to the -Region parameter or from the configured shell default))

There's no firewall issue and on the server that fails I CAN reach out to my AWS account using SyncbackPro - the third party Backup management tool.

Comment: Not sure it's of any help, but I keep getting this when I've got lousy internet access.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the region parameter in with the command to see if that helps: 
`Get-S3Bucket -Region eu-west-1`

Otherwise, do you have a proxy server which could be in the way? Or a proxy client that you need to bypass? `Set-AWSProxy` can be used for that

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was TLS version issue. After executing the following command everything got to work:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Found it here: https://www.codyhosterman.com/2016/06/force-the-invoke-restmethod-powershell-cmdlet-to-use-tls-1-2/

Answer (score 0):

Run aws configure on the machine where you are seeing this error. Check what is the default region configured. It should be same as the S3 bucker region. If that is not the case, you need to pass -region parameter in your get request.

Comment: Thanks this is our config on all 3 machines but still that sever complains:  
                                                                                                              
     Set-AWSCredential -AccessKey ABC -SecretKey 123 -StoreAs aws-access

Initialize-AWSDefaultConfiguration -ProfileName aws-access -Region eu-west-1 added to Powershell Profile

Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWSTools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell\AWSPowerShell.psd1" Added to Powershell profile

Comment: So the region is in the PS profile and also can be set on the fly but Get-S3Bucket still returns that error

Comment: Can I connect using AWS for Powershell Tool to my S3 bucket from a different region. 
AWS for powershell server location                          = eu-west-2
S3 Bucket location                                                     = eu-west-1

Comment: please take a look at this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-installing-specifying-region.html

Comment: Thansk @Shetty - but my region is 100% set correctly.. I've doen this the normal way with Set command, then in the appData json file, in my default profile, in my cre4ated profile.. You name it I've checked. The command "get-S3Bucket" continues to show the error above

Comment: @Shetty Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm running into something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Having same error. Spent tons of time and seems no one giving correct answer on the internet.

Cause for my issue:

I set a lab proxy in my Internet Explorer and I switched the proxy off today.
It seems the AWS powershell picked up the proxy setting from my IE.

Solution:
Removed proxy from IE then relaunched powershell, now working like a charm